# Select a sorted list by ranking across columns

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Using the table code below I was asked to draw out a list sorted by the rankings of each item. Each column rank# is how each user would rank that item. So for an item A if it was ranked 1 by one user and 16 by another its overall ranking should be 8. Is there a possible SQL query for this or process it in PHP?

```
CREATE TABLE `rankings` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rank1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rank2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rank3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rank4` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rank5` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rank6` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rank7` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rank8` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rank9` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rank10` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rank11` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rank12` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rank13` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rank14` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rank15` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `rank16` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `submissionTimestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Here is the table that each rank# column is referenced to:

```
CREATE TABLE `rankableItems` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`itemName` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you take it the wrong way. Here what you could do that will be much more simple to work with and to understand :

```
create table `ranking` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `item_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `item_rank` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL
)
```

And the associated query to get the average ranking :

```
SELECT AVG(item_rank) AS AVG_RANK 
FROM ranking 
WHERE item_id = 'xxx'
```

Comment: Unfortunately table was created from an already completed excel document - starting from scratch I'd like to have it that way but I'm kinda stuck with a large number of answers already in this format.

Comment: You could migrate your data into this new table :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you just want to find an average ranking.  I tried looking through some MySQL documentation, but couldn't find anything to directly calculate the average, so you will have to do it manually or within PHP.

To do it in MySQL, you can use:

```
SELECT (R.rank1 + R.rank2 + R.rank3 + R.rank4 + R.rank5 + R.rank6 + R.rank7 + R.rank8 + R.rank9 + R.rank10 + R.rank11 + R.rank12 + R.rank13 + R.rank14 + R.rank15 + R.rank16) / 16
AS row_avg FROM rankings R;
```

You can probably do it more dynamically in PHP using `array_sum()` and `count()` or something along those lines.